# Prevent printing blank pages

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, print-preview

I just need to reset "border" after print previewing. I preview the page I wantted to print correctly but when I do printing it gives blank pages because "border" wasnt reset. Where should I put "border=0"?("border" is no. rows in a datagridview)

```
  private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);           
        PrintPreviewDialog ppd = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        ppd.Document = pd;
        ppd.ShowDialog();

    }
  private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
  prntt(sender, e);
     }
   public void prntt(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
           for (; border < ViewA.RowCount; border++)
        {
            if (ustsin + yuk > e.MarginBounds.Bottom - 400f)
            {

                e.HasMorePages = true;                  

                return;
            }



            texts = ViewA.Rows[border].Cells["Persons"].Value.ToString();
            ...
            graphics.DrawString(texts, font, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(e.MarginBounds.Left, ustsin, 115f, 90f));               
            ...

            float hoho = (float)e.Graphics.MeasureString(texts, font, 115, StringFormat.GenericTypographic).Height;
            ...
            var mesele = new float[] { hoho, koko, moko };
            float kapa = mesele.OrderByDescending(s => s).First();

            ustsin += kapa + yuk;             

        }            

        e.HasMorePages = false;
     }
```

if I can close when we press the print button in print preview, can I reset in its closing event?

edit: I did this, it seems to work but when I send it to xps, it shows 2 pages in the screen. like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i9QZ.png . How can I make this show 1 page?

```
    private void printDocument1_EndPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
    {


        border = 0;
    }
```

Comment: That needs to go in your BeginPrint event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initially set it to `0` and reset it after `ppd.ShowDialog();`

```
ppd.ShowDialog();
border = 0;
```

### UPDATE

Looks like `PrintPreviewDialog` doesn't support much as you (and many others expect), it's up to the user (not to programmer). You can try this a little hacky stuff:

```
//code in your button5_Click
ToolStripButton onePageButton = ((ToolStrip)ppd.Controls[1]).Items[3] as ToolStripButton;
BeginInvoke((Action)(() => onePageButton.PerformClick()));
ppd.ShowDialog();
```

### UPDATE

To intercept the `Clicking` on the `Print button`, you have to add a little much more code. You have to detect the click before the `Click` is fired on the item (print button), show the message box asking for confirmation and `re-click` the item if user agrees. Here is the code for you:

```
//Use this class to add message interceptor into your ToolStrip message loop
public class NativeToolStrip : NativeWindow {
    ToolStrip ts;
    bool letClicked;
    protected override void OnHandleChange() {
        base.OnHandleChange();
        Control c = Control.FromHandle(Handle);
        ts = c as ToolStrip;
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {                
      if (m.Msg == 0x202&&!letClicked) {//WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202
           int x = m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0x00ff;
           int y = m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16;
           ToolStripItem item = ts.GetItemAt(new Point(x, y));                    
           //check if the first item (the Print Button) is clicked
           if (item != null && ts.Items.IndexOf(item) == 0) {
             if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to print?", "Print confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
                 return;//discard message
             else {
                    letClicked = true;
                    item.PerformClick();
              }
            }
       }
       base.WndProc(ref m);
       if (letClicked) letClicked = false;
    }
}
//This code should be done somewhere like in your form constructor
//BUT your PrintPreviewDialog should also be declared once in the form scope
//You can also place this in your button5_Click BUT it's not recommended
ToolStrip ts = (ToolStrip)ppd.Controls[1];
new NativeToolStrip().AssignHandle(ts.Handle);
```

Comment: it is not dropping there until I close preview window. is it possible close preview window when we press print button?

Comment: can you check the bottom of my question?

Comment: @emmett not sure if there is a more elegant solution but until you find it, try the solution in my UPDATE. I don't think there is any `straightway` here.

Comment: I see. I got one more question. How can I control print button on the print priview? I mean I want to show a Yes/No dialog when you press print button.

Comment: @emmett see my update, if you have more questions, please accept the answer first and ask in another question, We don't answer questions **in chain** like this.

Comment: you'r right. but this time I got more relevant question to ur answer. how can I access a dgv from under "item.PerformClick"? Thanks.